# How to knit rpart.plot function in r to pdf?

Tags: r, pdf, knitr

I try for a small university project to make a pdf with some plots from the rpart.plot package. I have written a small .rmd below.

I copied these functions from the help page in R.

If I make a plot before using an rpart.plot this issue does not occur, if the plot happens in same Rchunk as rpart.plot is called first time.
But in this project, I don´t want to create a plot before using rpart.plot.

Thanks for your help.

````
---
title: "Untitled"

author: "smurfit"

date: "5 Dezember 2017"

output: pdf_document
---
```{r}

library("rpart")
library("rpart.plot")

old.par <- par(mfrow=c(1,1))                    # put 1 figure on one page

data(ptitanic)

binary.model <- rpart(survived ~ ., data=ptitanic, cp=.02)
                      # cp=.02 for small demo tree
rpart.plot(binary.model,
           main="titanic survived\n(binary response)")

rpart.plot(binary.model,
           box.palette="Grays",         # override default GnBu palette
           main="titanic survived\nbox.palette = \"Grays\"")
´´´
````

Comment: For me your RMD knits fine WHEN you replace the last three `´´´` with ```.

Comment: I still get this error: "no information available on parameters from previous call to plot()"